# VIMDIFF missing small differences

Tags: vimdiff

I have two nearly identical very large files (890,000+ rows of exactly 899 characters each fixed length file).

On rows 289141-289148 one file has a pipe character in column 38, and the other file has a space in that position.

If I force vimdiff to look at them line by line, it finds the difference.  For example, if I delete and reinsert the line, vim finds the difference.  But, when I first opened the files, vim presented them as having no differences. Also, when I run `:diffupdate`, vim does not recognize the difference.

Is this a defect in VimDiff, or can you think of something I might be doing incorrectly?

From first file:

```
ABCDEFGH            ABCDEFGHI44    }"|                           S
```

From second file:

```
ABCDEFGH            ABCDEFGHI44    }"                            S
```

Also note: I tested the theory that it was something special about the pipe character.  Even when I replaced the pipes with a normal character (e.g., `j`), it still had the same behavior of not recognizing the difference.

Comment: With just the example lines you gave, vimdiff instantly highlights the differences for me. I suspect it is a size issue (vim doesn't always deal well with humongous texts, for memory reasons).

Comment: I concur - I assume it has something to do with very small differences in very large files.  Just wondering what those parameters are so I know when (if?) I can rely on the tool.

Comment: what vim version are you trying this with? Does it make a difference if you diffopt contains `internal` or not?

Comment: I diff two files and then choose help->Version.  That yields: VIM - Vi Improved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled May 19 2018 18:36:07).  I'm on a corporate network so I cannot just go download the current version. Interestingly, now the compare is identifying the expected difference.  Not sure what changed, if anything, or if it is random?

Comment: please try to replicate this behaviour, add additional context like the output of `:version` and check, whether adding/removing `internal` from the `diffopt` setting changes anything.